# Not able to execute Second Test Method in Nunit selinium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am using Selinium webdriver, Nunit framework and working with IE browser. I have the below code. Tt is not executing second method(add hazard). I am pasting code and stack trace. Could some one let me know where it went wrong.
Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


namespace Nunit2
   {
    [TestFixture]
     class SeleniumTest
    {
       public IWebDriver driver;

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
         public void SetUp()
        {
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Selenium_App\IE DriverServer_32bit2.48.0");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://testwebsite");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6000));
            IWebElement loginbutton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Image2"));
            loginbutton.Click();
            System.Console.WriteLine("page title is" + driver.Title);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Loginlogin")).SendKeys("AutomationUser");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Loginpassword")).SendKeys("safety35");
            IWebElement log = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginButton_DoLogin"));
            log.Click();
        }
        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
        }
        [Test]
        public void AddAction()
        {
            //  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.riskmanager.co.nz/");
           // driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6000));
            //IWebElement loginbutton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Image2"));
            //loginbutton.Click();
            //System.Console.WriteLine("page title is" + driver.Title);
            //driver.FindElement(By.Id("Loginlogin")).SendKeys("AutomationUser");
            //driver.FindElement(By.Id("Loginpassword")).SendKeys("safety35");
            //IWebElement log = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginButton_DoLogin"));
            //log.Click();
            //  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            IWebElement actionsMenu = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span[1]"));
            action.MoveToElement(actionsMenu).Build().Perform();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span")).Click();
            IWebElement actiontitle = driver.FindElement(By.Id("actrpnlActionTitleInputtitle"));
            actiontitle.SendKeys("Testaction");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("actrpnlDateDueInputdatedue")).SendKeys("16 Nov 16");
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("actrpnlReportingLineInputpnlLineDropdownlineid"));
            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(element);
            select.SelectByValue("196E");
            IWebElement PersonResponsible = driver.FindElement(By.Id("actrpnlPersonResponsibleInputempText"));
            PersonResponsible.SendKeys("a");
            IWebElement se = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//html/body/ul[2]/li/a"));
            se.Click();
            IWebElement Addaction = driver.FindElement(By.Id("actrButton_Insert"));
            Addaction.Click();
        }
        [Test]
        public void AddHazard()
        {
            Actions hazard = new Actions(driver);
            IWebElement hazardmenu = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[3]/ul/li[3]/a/span[1]"));
            hazard.MoveToElement(hazardmenu).Build().Perform();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[3]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[1]/a/span")).Click();
            System.Console.WriteLine("second test");
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

est Name:   AddHazard
Test FullName:  Nunit2.SeleniumTest.AddHazard
Test Source:    C:\Users\Anuradh Vanguri\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Nunit2\Nunit2\Class1.cs : line 72
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:38.151

Result StackTrace:
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line 154
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line 114
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\DriverServiceCommandExecutor.cs:line 78
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 910
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 954
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String xpath) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 700
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__c(ISearchContext context) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\By.cs:line 167
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\By.cs:line 309
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 330
   at Nunit2.SeleniumTest.AddHazard() in C:\Users\Anuradh Vanguri\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Nunit2\Nunit2\Class1.cs:line 74
--WebException
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line 141
--IOException
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
--SocketException
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
Result Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:61917/session/a992c864-0c93-45dc-bec8-0d74e68ecceb/element. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
  ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 0):

[TestFixture] requires a public class

```
 [TestFixture]
 public class SeleniumTest
```

[From Nunit's documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a timeout between interactions with IE driver.

Look at this topic, some IE problems are discussed:
[Selenium error: No response from server for url http://localhost:7055](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321991/selenium-error-no-response-from-server-for-url-http-localhost7055)