# Change in hardware on VM, run tests parallel without any code change Visual Studio MSTests, every test fails

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, virtual-machine, processor

I'm writing my test cases on a VM. It is a single processor and used to be very very slow, nut all the tests used to pass running one at a time. But now they upgraded my VM to 4 virtual processors. Now when I run tests all at a time, 4 threads start and 4 test cases are getting selected. That's pretty fast and happy to see tests are running in parallel.

But now the problem is each and every test case is failing. They seem to run pretty fast. I'm getting different types of exceptions for the tests. I have nearly 100 test cases now. If I run one test case at a time, they all pass. I can't even think of a single solution for it. I want to run my tests in parallel as new test cases keep on adding to the suite.

I am using Selenium Server to test a web application. The test failure errors I am getting are different, it's not just one. Some are getting no such element exception, some getting stale element exception, some unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 milliseconds, no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it...

If I run tests one at a time, they are passing.

Here is an example Stack Trace:

```
Test Name:  User_SearchBox
Test FullName:  SDTestAutomation.Users_Tests.User_SearchBox
Test Source:    c:\Git\AutomationTest\automationtest\AutomationTest\SDTestAutomation\Users_Tests.cs : line 42
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:02:12.2258535

Result Message: 
Test method SDTestAutomation.Users_Tests.User_SearchBox threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7058/hub/session/42d497d6-866c-4f3e-bad2-bc7d90068a30/element/%7B1b33a253-13e9-406f-9ba1-825b6ab34f48%7D/click. The status of the exception was ConnectionClosed, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
TestCleanup method SDTestAutomation.Users_Tests.QuitBrowser threw exception. System.Exception: System.Exception: Logout button is not clicked.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
at SDTestAutomation.Users_Tests.User_SearchBox() in c:\Git\AutomationTest\automationtest\AutomationTest\SDTestAutomation\Users_Tests.cs:line 49

TestCleanup Stack Trace
at SmartDebitTestFramework.HomePage.get_Logout() in c:\Git\AutomationTest\automationtest\AutomationTest\SmartDebitTestFramework\HomePage.cs:line 422
at SDTestAutomation.Users_Tests.QuitBrowser() in c:\Git\AutomationTest\automationtest\AutomationTest\SDTestAutomation\Users_Tests.cs:line 407
```

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to answer this without seeing the structure of your tests, a failure log, and/or some test code, unless it so happens that this is a common problem for all VS-based test suites.

Comment: The errors are different, it's not just one. Some are getting no such element exception, some getting stale element exception, some unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 milliseconds, no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it...

Comment: Were you previously able to run your tests in any order and/or individually? Does any test input rely on the output of another test?

Comment: Before the upgrade of my machine, though the tests used to take more time to run, they get passed but now no test is passing. Even a simple login validation test case fails.

Comment: My tests are independent of each other. No test is dependent on other test or it's output.

Comment: OK, that's good. If you run the tests individually _now_, do they all still pass? Also (separate question), are you able to configure your tests to use one core without contacting the VM admin to see if this fixes it?

Comment: It sounds you can at least reliably replicate the problem. Are you able to [take a screenshot](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=selenium+server+screenshot) in Selenium to see what is going on?

Comment: I added the stack trace, When I run tests I noticed, one test failed and immediately the other tests running failed in a second. If I run them individually one at a time, they are passing.

Comment: I didn't configure my tests and I don't know how to do that. I didn't take any screen shot, I didn't code my tests to take a screen shot.

Comment: OK, two things to start researching on! The core configuration is just a temporary fix, since of course you'd want to use parallelisation if possible. I am now not sure about screenshotting since your stack trace seems to indicate a low-level error in Selenium, so taking a screenshot may not help. Still, it might be worth a go.

Comment: [The answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221178/472495) suggests a delay between tests (although that's for the IE driver, and does not sound ideal). Perhaps do some searching on the error messages you get, in case this is a common issue?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Will try to go deep with the tests and will get back to you if I find a solution or the reason for the errors.

Comment: For screenshots i added this code in Test Cleanup, but I couldn't see a screenshot saved to my PC. Where will they get saved by default?  'Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)Drivers._driverInstance).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile("ss.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);'

Comment: I'm not sure, it's been ages since I've used Selenium. Maybe try triggering a screenshot on a single successful test? It's worth checking the screenshot code works `:-)`

Comment: Also try setting the number of parallel browsers to 1 in your Selenium Server start-up ([see here](http://blog.wedoqa.com/2013/07/how-to-run-parallel-tests-with-selenium-webdriver-and-testng-2/)) to see if that temporarily fixes it.