# Command line server for the IE Driver has stopped working

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I had this issue when I trying to run latest `IEDriver 2.50.1`, its waits and after a couple seconds crushes.

In the command line its say's: only local connections are allowed. Maybe that's the problem and how can I change it

I tried to find solution for that problem but nothing clear.

**My driver initialization:**

```
InternetExplorerDriverService driverService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
//driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driverService.LibraryExtractionPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnableNativeEvents = true;
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

**Exception:**

> A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to
>   the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:61152/session.
>   The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was:
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

**Error Image:**

[image: Application crushes image]

What can it be? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using IEDriver  2.50.1 or 2.50.0 (from the console) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321991/selenium-error-no-response-from-server-for-url-http-localhost7055

Comment: i tried changing the versions but still the same..

Comment: only after windows restart the application begin to work.